# Granada 2 euro refund Credibus

Tags: public-transport, europe, spain

I read online that we can get a 2 euro refund for the Granada bus travel passes (credibus) but where exactly do we go? What if we bought the pass via a vending machine?

Has anyone here actually managed to get refunds?

Comment: [This website](https://www.lovegranada.com/transport/granada-bus-fares) says otherwise: *You pay 2 euros for the card and top it up with 5, 10, 20 euros. When you leave Granada, 2 euros are not refunded*

Comment: update: i checked with one tobacco shop and was redirected to red busess. I checked with 2 red bus drivers but they both refused to return any credit. Replies were in Spanish so couldn’t get much tbh.

Answer (score 4):

[According to](https://ctagr.es/sistema-tarifario/tarjeta-de-transporte/preguntas-frecuentes) the Granada Area Metropolitan Transport Consortium:

> **¿Y si ya no quiero usarla más?**
>
> Tiene la posibilidad de devolver la tarjeta en cualquiera de los puntos de venta / distribución asociados al Consorcio. En la devolución sólo se devuelve la fianza que pagó por la tarjeta nunca el saldo restante.

or, in English (my translation, unofficial):

> **And if I don't want to use it any more?**
>
> You have the possibility to return the card in any of the [sales/distribution points](https://siu.ctagr.es/es/puntos_de_venta.php) associated with the Consortium. The refund will only be for the fee that you paid for the card, not for any remaining credit.

Comment: +1 Translation looks fine to me.

Comment: update: i checked with one tobacco shop and was redirected to red busess. I checked with 2 red bus drivers but they both refused to return any credit. Replies were in Spanish so couldn’t get much tbh.